# How to save the name instead of the Id in Cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp

I have a simple question and I'm a beginner in CakePHP.
so, I have a table in my database named "countries". in my view "add.ctp" (a view that add a new "LCC") I have created a dropdown list of countries using my table.

The problem is that when I save my new "LCC", CakePHP saves the id (which in my case is named "code") of the table countries instead of the name of the table(countries).

in my controller function add:

```
$this->loadModel('countries');
    $this->set('country', $this->countries->find('list',array('fields'=>array('countries.name','countries.code'))));
```

in my view add.ctp:

```
<?php echo $this->Form->input('destination_export', array('label' => '','class'=>'form-control','options'=>$country,'value'=>''));?>
```

any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What version of CakePHP are you using?

Comment: 3.
thank you for your response, but i just find the solution.
in my model ->coutiresTable i changed "$this->primaryKey('code');" to "$this->primaryKey('name');"

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, when asking questions please always mention the _exact_ CakePHP version you're using (last line in `vendor/cakephp/cakephp/VERSION.txt`) - thanks. From your code it looks like you could possibly use CakePHP 2, which however isn't the case. In CakePHP 3, list finders are being configured differently. That being said, if that column isn't the actual primary key, then you really shouldn't define it as such!

Comment: thank you, i'll not use this table a lot in my project that's why i'm not really caring about the primary key thing.